# Magento Theme Broke after Upgrading to 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, error, theme, upgrade, magento-upgrade

We recently had to update our Magento to allow support for a crucial plugin on our website, however on updating to 2.2.5 the frontend shows lots of errors.
What would of caused this and how can it be fixed?

Errors:
https://pastebin.com/Dd5tmGnK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due the mycrpt is not enabled in your server. You have to enable mycrpt.

You can enable it by following command in your apache server:

```
sudo apt-get install php7-mcrypt
```

Then restart the server by below command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: We have shared hosting using cPanel, it says in the php config that this package is enabled: https://i.imgur.com/5g9EB5d.png

Comment: This type of issue is related to missing mycrpt in the server. Can you ask your server provider?

Comment: Ahh okay ill get in touch with them, will this fix all the errors on that stacktrace?